# AlertIOS For loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having an issue with AlertIOS

```
var array =[];
for (var i = 1; i <= sortedResult.length; i++) {      
  array.push({
    text: sortedResult[i].name,
    onPress: () => this.upload(i)
  });
}
AlertIOS.alert(
  'Question ?',
  null,
  array
);
```

The problem is that the variable i in the for loop is not replaced by its value:

```
{text: sortedResult[i].name, onPress: () => this.upload(i)}

{text: sortedResult[i].name, onPress: () => this.upload(i)}
...
```

instead of

```
{text: sortedResult[1].name, onPress: () => this.upload(1)}

{text: sortedResult[2].name, onPress: () => this.upload(2)}
...
```

I don't know whether it is specific to javascript or specific to react.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a map

```
array = sortedResult.map((r, index) => {      
  return {
    text: r.name,
    onPress: () => this.upload(index)
  };
}
```

in general this is a very common mistake with beginner javascript developers. See [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It is preferred in the community to make use of `map` or `forEach` over for loops.